# Custom style for syntax highlighting in Atom

Tags: less, atom-editor

I'm trying to adjust the header style for markdown files in Atom. I've put the following rule in my `styles.less`, but it doesn't make any difference:

```
.source.gfm .markup.heading {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Other rules like `.tree-view { font-size: 13px; }` work, so I'm sure the file is being read. I've also tried to add `!important`, but of no avail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

My syntax 90s-tshirt styles the markdown headings this way :

```
.source.gfm .markup {
  &.heading {
    color: @blue;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

*The key is :* not every element you can style in markdown will be wrapped under the .source or .gfm classes in Atom. Plus, the .gfm class is sometimes put straight on the target element, sometimes not at all.

Copy/Paste some markdown code with as many different cases inside as possible (typography, lists, tables etc.), and look not only at direct wrappers, but up to 4 or 5 imbrications blocks over one target element in their HTML.

Bonus :
If you want to easily get more stylable classes I have styled with success for **markdown**, look at [my source file](https://github.com/melinadonati/90s-tshirt-syntax/blob/master/styles/base.less), and CTRL+F in your web browser, then search "markup" and you'll be right on the lines.